# telnetlib - interactive console vs script

Tags: python, interactive, telnetlib

The problem is, my script won't work (it's printing empty lane), but it works in python interactive console.

```
import telnetlib

tn = telnetlib.Telnet("killermud.pl", 4000)
data = tn.read_very_eager()
data = data.decode()
print(data)
tn.close()
```

What is the reason of such behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just took a look at the documentation for the `read_very_eager` method, which says:

> Read all data available already queued or on the socket,
>   without blocking.

It is likely that at the time you call this method that there is no data "already available or queued on the socket", so you're getting nothing back.  You probably want to use something like the `read_until` method, which will read data until it finds a specific string.  For example:

```
data = tn.read_until('Podaj swoje imie')
```

Comment: It's not the reason. This script works perfectly fine if i run it under interactive console.

Comment: Actually, I think it *is* the reason, because when running under the interactive console there will be more time between opening the connection and calling `read_very_eager`, which means that there is a better chance the socket has data available.  You could put a `time.sleep` before the the `read_very_eager` call to reproduce this behavior, but that's the wrong solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to tlnetlib documentation, Telnet.read_very_eager() Raises EOFError if connection closed and no cooked data available. Return '' if no cooked data available otherwise. Do not block unless in the midst of an IAC sequence.
If you do data=="", returns true, Therefore, it means that no cooked data is available